# How to render a skin in Teeworlds?

Tags: teeworlds

I use a standard skin with **custom** colors and want to get a picture of my skin. One can find and download a rendered skin picture from https://ddnet.tw/skins/, but only with **standard** colors:

[image: bluekitty]

How to get an image like this, but with custom body/feet colors that I use in the game?

**UPD**: ↓ this is happy me after solving the problem

[image: belkka][image: happy belkka]

Comment: [Got an answer](https://discord.com/channels/252358080522747904/745926398140612678/955949267913158656) from a user at [DDRaceNetwork discord server](https://discord.com/invite/22sqGcB)

Comment: It's cool seeing a tee worlds question here, it's such an underrated game.  =)